# JavaFx CSS Error parsing Unexpected token ':' at [15,21]

Tags: java, css, javafx

I can't explain why there is an error at line 15 when there is no such error at line 21. Clean and rebuilding doesn't help.

my css file :

```
#i-will-do-it
{
    -fx-fill: #3AA8C1; /* moonstone */
  /*  -fx-fill: #6F2DA8; /* Grape */
}

#background
{
    -fx-background-color: #353839; /* Onyx */
}

#minute
{
    -fx-stroke: #3F26BF /* Ultramarine Blue */
    -fx-stroke-width : 3; /* THIS IS LINE 15 */
}

#seconds
{
    -fx-stroke: #FD0E35; /* scarlet */
    -fx-stroke-width : 0.8; /* THIS IS LINE 21 */
}

#hour
{
    -fx-stroke: #3F26BF; /* Ultramarine Blue */
    -fx-stroke-width : 5;
}
```

You can see that my line 15 hasn't turned blue :
[image]

Comment: you are missing a `;`. should have been  `#3F26BF;`

Comment: @Tushortz really sorry. i will be deleting this question and thanks. been here for an hour

Comment: The [15, 21] means line 15, position 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semicolon missing at the end of line 14. The error you're seeing may be related to that.